# Is there a language in NSPACE(O(n)) and (very likely) not in DSPACE(O(n))?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np-complete, space-complexity

Actually I found that the set of context-sensitive Languages, 
$\mathbf{CSL}$ ($\mathbf{=NSPACE}(O(n))$ $= \mathbf{LBA}$ accepted languages) are not so widely discussed as $\mathbf{REG}$ (regular languages) or $\mathbf{CFL}$ (context-free languages).

And also the open problem $\mathbf{DSPACE}(O(n)) \stackrel?= \mathbf{NSPACE}(O(n))$ is not so famous as the "analogous" problem: $\mathbf{P} \stackrel?= \mathbf{NP}$.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a language in $\mathbf{CSL}$ which couldn't be proved to be in $\mathbf{DSPACE}(O(n))$?
2. Moreover: Is there a language $L$ in $\mathbf{CSL}$ which is "complete" in the following sense: if we can prove that $L$ is in $\mathbf{DSPACE}(O(n))$ we get that $\mathbf{DSPACE}(O(n)) = \mathbf{CSL}$?

Notice:
I have asked these questions in cs.stackexchange and got some interesting Answers but not a *concrete (proven)* example for such a language:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79528/a-language-in-nspaceon-and-very-likely-not-in-dspaceon

Comment: Neat question!  :)

Comment: Just take any language complete for NSPACE(n) under linear-time reductions.

Comment: $NPSPACE=NSPACE(poly(n))=DSPACE(poly(n))=PSPACE$ So my prior is that $NSPACE(O(n))$ and $DSPACE(O(n))$ are fairly close and not analogous to $P$ versus $NP$.

Comment: @Thomas, I already pointed that this is more analogous to $L$ vs. $NL$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Are there many known $\mathbf{CSL}$-languages which are complete under linear-time reductions?  Can you recommend a book or link for this?

Comment: I don’t know what is *many*, but it’s certainly straightforward to construct examples of such languages: e.g., $L_1=\{\langle M,w\rangle:\text{$M$ is an NTM and accepts $w$ within space $|w|$}\}$, or $L_2={}$ succinct $s$-$t$-connectivity (i.e., the set of Boolean circuits $C$ in $2n$ variables such that there is a directed path from $\vec0$ to $\vec1$ in the directed graph on vertex set $\{0,1\}^n$ whose edge relation is computed by $C$). Surely some such have been given in the literature, but I can’t point you to a book.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks! I meant with "many" something like the sites with $\mathbf{NP}$-complete problems, e.g.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems